# How to get a more compact view of the site activity

Tags: customization

The snapshot below shows what I see when I click on the "See all" link on the top right of the Activity view in the Home page of a group site.

It's a horrible waste of real estate and makes the page unusabale.

I know about 200 files have been modified today, but I can't have the picture of what files have been modified. Even searching for them with `Ctrl+F` is out of question because I can't see their names until I scroll.

Is it possible to show this list as a, well, a list instead of this useless ugly cards?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer - you can't change the Site Activity View. There are no settings you can possible tweak to make changes to the way this page is presented to you.

The Activity Webpart also lacks any settings:
[image]

You could develop a custom SharePoint framework webpart that would pull the same data and present it in a more compact way.

Comment: Well... didn't solve the problem and didn't help finding a solution, but I guess this is the correct answer anyway :(